# How to create temporary links with simple JWT in Django Rest Framework and React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm new to JWT tokens and I want to know if there is a way to create temporary links with simple JWT tokens, I already use JWT tokens for authentication in my app, if there is not a way to do this what is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create and verify tokens with [Token](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/1c7f0051178a826390262c68557b69eeeeec71aa/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py#L15) class.

This class has `for_user` class method to create token for specific users and `verify` method to verify the links.

[link to for_user](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/1c7f0051178a826390262c68557b69eeeeec71aa/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py#L154)

[link to verify method](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/1c7f0051178a826390262c68557b69eeeeec71aa/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py#L82)